# How do I setup a project in Eclipse for JSP, Servlet, JPA, Hibernate web development

Tags: java, eclipse, hibernate, jsp, servlets

I am a newbie to Hibernate.

I have a school project using MySQL, JDBC, JSP/Servlet, Tomcat technologies.

The way that I do the database connection in EVERY Servlet is:

1. establish database connection in JDBC.
2. create Query statement and execute it.
3. close database connection.

That is very very tedious, so I want to use JPA with Hibernate to handle it.

I looked some tutorials and saw that there's a JPA Project option in Eclipse, so went ahead and used it.

Now I am confused about how to add JSP/Servlet into this project. It seems like this type project is not meant for handling any front-end technologies.

Could anyone please help me clear this out? What type of eclipse project should I use in my case?

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use whatever Eclipse project templates you want, they just setup directory structure and libraries for convenience.  You could start with a normal Java project if you wanted, it's just a matter of understanding what libraries/dependencies to setup.  My personal preference is to use the Dynamic Web Project so it set's up my web directory structure and web.xml.

Adding JPA/Hibernate to a project consists of:

1) Mapping your classes (annotations or xml)
2) Creating the EntityManagerFactory/SessionFactory
3) Inject the Factory where you need database access

If this is your first non-trivial database application take a look at the [DAO Pattern](http://java.sun.com/blueprints/corej2eepatterns/Patterns/DataAccessObject.html).  It will help you understand how to abstract away database specific decisions (e.g. JDBC vs Hibernate vs JPA) from your application logic.

Comment: link is broken btw

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what tutorial and information you have looked at. There are good information that is available, but to start you can take a quick look some myeclipse tutorials [here](http://www.myeclipseide.com/documentation/quickstarts/jpa/) and the one's up here are [good](http://tv.jetbrains.net/channel/intellij-idea). Cheers.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have some ideas about how _JPA_ works, but I don't how to configure eclipse to create a project that handle both front-end and middle-layer technologies. Say I have a table called _Customer_. I can create an _ORM_ with that table, but with eclipse _JPA Project_ option. It seems like that's it. The question is where should I add _Servlet/JSP_ to that project. It doesn't have a _WebContent_ folder that comes with it, and I cannot add that project to a Web Server in eclipse. Should I create another _Dynamic Web Project_? Then how do I handle Inter-project communication?